# how to give a hash or signature of network made with networkx on python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, hash, networkx, pickle, signature

i need to check a network made with python3 and networkx if it has recently changed. If the network has been modified on server side, i need
to draw a new graph (.png) and refresh client with websocket.
If i have multiple networks, i want to compare them, i could compare signatures of both.

So, how can i get a hash or kind of signature of an networkx instance ?
Same question for a serialized network.

i dont know how to compare networks (counting nodes and edges is not sufficient)
for the same amount, networks can be different (ie weight of one edge can differ)

Comment: Can nodes be renamed? If so, does renaming a node count as a modification?

Comment: `networkx` graphs are just python objects, so you could 1) pickle the graph with `write_gpickle`, and 2) compute an md5sum using `hashlib`, then 3) compare hashes for different network instances.

Comment: Personally, though, I would subclass the `Graph` class and wrap any methods that are being used server side to change the graph to set a flag that the method has been invoked and that stuff needs to be redrawn.

Comment: thanks for your help paul